# Write active states for nav based on clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a unique global nav that is used for vertical parallax pages as well as static sub pages etc.

I would like to add active states. Of `border-bottom: 2px solid red;` and `padding-bottom: 26px;`

I have successfully added them to click function with the below code. Though I think it's a bit clunky.

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').click(function () {
        $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css('text-decoration', 'none');
     $(this).css('border-bottom', '2px solid red');
     $(this).css('padding-bottom', '26px');
     });
 });
```

**Problem:**

*After I click one nav item, the active state appears, but then I click another item and still the previous active state of previous click is displaying. I need to remove a previous binded css or activate state once new nav item is clicked. Any suggestions?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of using inline styles (jquery `.css()`), make a CSS class with the style
2. Use jQuery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()` - with appropriate selectors.

First remove it from all, then add it to the active one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pen for changing classes
http://codepen.io/easingthemes/pen/gbgevd

Inline CSS (not recommended)

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').click(function () {
        $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({
            textDecoration: 'underline',
            borderBottom: 'none',
            paddingBottom: 'none'
        })
        $(this).css({
            textDecoration: 'none',
            borderBottom: '2px solid red',
            paddingBottom: '26px'
        });

    });
});
```

JS toggle classes (recommended)

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').click(function () {
        $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').removeClass('.active');
        $(this).addClass('.active');
     });
 });
```

CSS

```
.active {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
}
```